# Java Interface implementation confusion

Tags: java

I have an interface in java, called Action
and has no functions

I also have an interface in java called State
which has this function

```
public Set<Action> getPossibleActions();
```

I have this enum

```
public enum Movement implements Action{...}
```

and this class

```
public class Tiles implements search.State{
```

which implements the function

```
    public Set<Movement> getPossibleActions() {...}
        Set<Movement> movements = new LinkedHashSet<Movement>();
...
        }
        return movements;
    }
```

Why my last function does not work? I get the message that the return type is incompatible with the function     public Set getPossibleActions();

As I set my class Movement to implement interface Action, my Movement isn't an Action? Therefore it should work...
What I am doing wrong?

How do I solve that?

Comment: `Movement` is an `Action`, but a `Set<Movement>` is not a `Set<Action>.`

Comment: Use `Set<? extends Action>` instead

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks a lot Sotiri :) And how I fix that? I can't find any way...

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks. If I used it correctly, this did not work for me

Comment: @Sebastian where I should add that? Because It seems that at the other question the answerers are responding by the same thing, but I cannot find where to put that? Should I do it to define the return type next to getPossibleActions()? or should I cast the movement I return. I tried both, but it does not work for me...

Comment: If you are adding to it use `Set<? super Action>` and if you are retrieving from it use `Set<? extends Action>` but if you need to do both you need to specify a specific type.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Prince But I still cant find out, how this could be used at my last function... As a return type, or a the type of the movements variable?

Comment: Either change the `interface` method to `public Set<? extends Action> getPossibleActions()` or change the implementation method to use `Set<Action>`. In the latter case you can still add instances of `Movement` to a `Set<Action>`.